# Best output file format for Photoshop

Tags: compositing-nodes, file-format

I want to use Photoshop for batch processing my images. What is the best file output for taking into photoshop?

I usually do openEXR multilayer when I use Blender's compositor.

Comment: keep your files as EXR http://www.exr-io.com/

Comment: Sounds like you already got the best format. It is an HDR based image, will keep real lighting values, supports multiple layers and passes, so can't get much better than that.

Comment: EXR is wonderful as the two excellent folks above have noted, _except_ in Photoshop. Photoshop, being a display referred application, will cause you no end of grief with EXRs depending on the information they contain. Difficult to provide a better answer without knowing more about the context however.